# Mean value theorem proof with tangent

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, inequality

I am trying to show that:

$\tan{x}>x$ for $0<x<\pi/2$.

How can I show this? I think I can do something with the fcn $\tan{x}-x$ and it derivative, but how can I use this in a proof?

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: what's the sign of both sine and cosine in the first quadrant...?

Comment: hmm, I'm intrigued by this as well, what does the positive sign of both tell us?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. Let $f(x)=\tan x-x$. Then $f(0)=0$. You want to show $f(x)>0$ if $0<x<\pi/2$. It will be enough to show that $f$ is increasing. But $f'(x)=\dots\ $ (fill in the blanks.)

Answer (score 1):

The function $\sec^{2}{x}$ has range $\left[0,\infty\right]$

Let $$f(x)=\tan{x}-x$$
$$f^{'}(x)=\sec^{2}{x}-1 \ge 0$$
Hence $f$ is increasing and note that $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)>f(0)\;\; \forall \frac{\pi}{2}>x>0$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

What does the derivative of the function tell you about the function in the first place? Slope of the function. If the slope is $+$ve(at all the points), you have an increasing function.